# Cannot import name StringIO when importing dateutil

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, importerror, python-dateutil

I'm having a 'Cannot import name StringIO' error message when importing `dateutil` which tries to import `StringIO` but cannot find it. Here is complete trace:

```
(DEV)arbi@el-oued:~/Work/sentimentpy$ python core/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from io.reader import *
  File "/home/arbi/Work/sentimentpy/core/io/reader.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser
  File "/home/arbi/DEV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 22, in <module>
    from io import StringIO
ImportError: cannot import name StringIO
```

When I tried to use `python3`  to launch my program, i had this error:

```
(DEV)arbi@el-oued:~/Work/sentimentpy$ python3 core/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from analyzer.length import LengthAnalyzer
  File "/home/arbi/Work/sentimentpy/core/analyzer/length.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Why I'm having this? i've installed `numpy` in my virtualenv with: `pip install numpy`

Comment: To install NumPy in Python 3 use `pip3`.

Comment: Seems you do not have numpy installed for python 3.

Comment: agree for numpy, but what about the StringIO, it's supposed to be part of the standard library no? should i installed too?

Comment: @Arbi There's a builtin module called `io`, so name your `io` package to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are masking the built-in `io` module because you have a package named `io` in your project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from io.reader import *
  File "/home/arbi/Work/sentimentpy/core/io/reader.py", line 4, in <module>
```

The line `from io import StringIO` finds `/home/arbi/Work/sentimentpy/core/io`, *not* the built-in module.

Rename that package or move it into a new top-level package name that doesn't conflict.

Your second error is unrelated; you simply don't have `numpy` installed for Python 3.