# Issue inheriting from Panda's DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extend the DataFrame object from the Pandas package, and I am getting a strange error that I can't solve.

```
import pandas as pd
###########################################################################
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name StringIO
```

If I write the above code directly in the python.exe interpreter, I do not get this error.  Why is this being thrown?

Installation information:

- Python 2.7.10
- Pandas version 0.18.1

Thanks

Comment: I ran it on my jupyter notebook and from a script with python 2.7 installed and it worked fine. Can you provide all information about your python install, and the script itself. Is this the entire class you are trying to use?

Comment: installation information above.  That is my whole class as of right now.

Comment: can you `import StringIO` in both interpreter and from script? try doing that first.

Comment: yes I can import StringIO

Comment: maybe check that you don't have a package or file in the same directory named `io` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947227/cannot-import-name-stringio-when-importing-dateutil, also might help to re-install pandas & numpy

Comment: @downshift i did reinstall and same issue. Very strange.